Probability Extremum Problem in Multivariate Stochastic Processes
In the process of learning quantitative finance, I encountered a mathematical proof problem related to stochastic processes, which can be simplified into the following form:
Point $A$ starts from $(0,0)$ and, upon reaching position $(i, j)$ where $i = 0, 1, \ldots, m-1$ and $j = 0, 1, \ldots, n-1$, moves one unit to the right to $(i+1, j)$ with probability $p^2(i, j)$ and one unit up to $(i, j+1)$ with probability $1 - p^2(i, j)$. Let $P_1$ denote the probability that the x-coordinate of point $A$ reaches $x = m$ before the y-coordinate reaches $y = n$. Point $B$ also starts from $(0,0)$ and, upon reaching position $(i, j)$ where $i = 0, 1, \ldots, m-1$ and $j = 0, 1, \ldots, n-1$, moves one unit to the right to $(i+1, j)$ with probability $1 - (1 - p(i, j))^2$ and one unit up to $(i, j+1)$ with probability $(1 - p(i, j))^2$. Let $P_2$ denote the probability that the y-coordinate of point $B$ reaches $y = n$ before the x-coordinate reaches $x = m$. Here, $0 < p(i, j) < 1$ for $i = 0, 1, \ldots, m-1$ and $j = 0, 1, \ldots, n-1$.
Prove that when $P_1 + P_2$ attains its minimum value, $p(i, j) = p$ for all $i = 0, 1, \ldots, m-1$ and $j = 0, 1, \ldots, n-1$, where $p \in (0,1)$ satisfies the following equation:
$\frac{ p^{2m-1}  (1 - p^2)^{n-1}}{(1 - p) ^{2n-1} \times (1 - (1 - p)^2)^{m-1}} = 1$

can you include a reference e.g. the name of the book?

also,please try to include some of your own attempts by editing your post.

I'm sorry, this question is an actual issue encountered by my teacher during the research process in economics. What I asked was just an abstract version of this actual issue. Currently, I have not found relevant content in books. To avoid revealing my teacher's research findings, I'm sorry I cannot provide information regarding the economic background

I am currently trying to prove the case where m = n, with p being 1/2, and the result is quite elegant. I am using mathematical induction and the convexity of multivariable functions to solve this simplified scenario, but I have not made significant progress yet
